# How to interpret this p-value

Tags: r, p-value, linear-model

I have the following R output from the `summary` of my linear model `lm(y ~ x)`:

`Multiple R-squared:  0.009909, Adjusted R-squared:  0.007681 
F-statistic: 4.010 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.03724`

What does the p-value of `0.03724` actually mean? I know it is between 0.01 and 0.05 so there is strong evidence to reject the hypothesis that ...?

Comment: In the absence of any distinguishing information about your situation, I have closed this as a duplicate of a generic question about interpreting p-values.

Comment: @whuber What are the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis here?